# Android - SEND Intent filter not working

Tags: android, google-chrome, url, android-intent, browser

In my android application, I have an intent filter linked to one of my activities in my `AndroidManifest.xml` like so:

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/name >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

By my understanding this should add my app the list of apps in my browser (Chrome) that are under the "Share..." section so that my app can use the URL of the current web page. This list contains Flipboard, Android Beam, Twitter, Keep, Google+, etcetera.

I've found many examples on how to do this, they all use the above code. However, my app doesn't show up on that list for some reason. What could be the reason for this and how can I solve this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are including the action and category correctly but you also need to include the `mimeTypes` so that the `Intent` knows what type of sharing you want to support. Try including these two lines in order to support both text and image sharing:

```
<data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
<data android:mimeType="image/*" />
```

Like so:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
    <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
</intent-filter>
```

If you then want to retrieve the URL from the `Intent` to utilise in your app then you'll want to add this code to your `onCreate()` method in `MainActivity`:

```
String action = intent.getAction(); 
if (action.equalsIgnoreCase(Intent.ACTION_SEND) && intent.hasExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT)) { 
    String URL = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
}
```

Comment: Okay, that seems to work, but how do I retrieve the website URL in my app?

Comment: @26hmkk I've updated my answer to help you with that too.

Comment: Thanks for all your help!

Comment: @26hmkk So that works and you can retrieve the URL in your app correctly?

Comment: @26hmkk Brilliant. No problem, glad to help!